# Yum search , install and list

Tags: fedora, yum

I have just started using Yum. Here are a couple of questions I have regarding Yum
The three commands that I have

```
A > yum install package_name  //search for package_name in local repo or the internet and install it
B > yum search package_name   //search for package_name in local repo or the internet
C > yum list                  //list installed packages and packages that are available in local repo and internet
```

1. Is my understanding of the above commands correct ?
2. What does the local repo mean ? Is it a directory that contains all
   the packages
3. How do I find what the default repo directory of yum is on my
   computer ?
4. How do I list all the packages that are available on my local repo only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is my understanding of the above commands correct ?

Yes

> 2. What does the local repo mean ? Is it a directory that contains all the packages

If you are configuring your own yum repository (or your system admin. in your lab) then it may refer as local yum repository. It may be on local system or on a private network. [Ref: How to configure yum repository](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Yum_Repository.html).

> 3. How do I find what the default repo directory of yum is on my computer?

This is configured in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. There is no such think as `default` here. If repository is enabled that means that is active. You can find enabled repos by:

```
# yum repolist enabled
```

> 4. How do I list all the packages that are available on my local repo only?

For this, I am running a query with help of this command:

```
# yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="myrepo" list available
```

where, replace `myrepo` with your repository name.